# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Hit not correct?

Tags: google-analytics, urlencode, measurement-protocol

I'm attempting to send hit payloads as part of a POST for the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol for my iOS android app.

Here's a hit I'm sending for session control:

```
&dp=scenes%2Estudio%2EScene&geoid=TESTING&z=818790&sr=480x270&ul=en&sc=start&ds=simulator&dl=scenes%2Estudio%2EScene&dr=iOS&tid=UA%2Dxxxxxxx%2D1&ti=TESTING&cid=TESTING&aip=1&an=FE&cd=scenes%2Estudio%2EScene&aid=xxx%2Eyyyy%2Ezzz%2E&v=1&av=16%2E5%2E2
```

And here's a hit I'm sending for an exception event:

```
&dp=scenes%2Emenu%2EScene&geoid=TESTING&z=217660&sr=480x270&ul=en&exf=1&ds=simulator&dl=scenes%2Emenu%2EScene&dr=iOS&aid=xxx%2Eyyy%2Ezzz%2E&ti=TESTING&cid=TESTING&tid=UA%2D117928712%2D1&exd=%2FUsers%2Fchomsky%2Fapps%2Ffunbox%2Fapps%2Fxxx%2Flib%2Fscamp%2Fdebug%2FmenuButtons%2FFE%2Elua%3A147%3A+822Error&aip=1&an=FE&cd=scenes%2Emenu%2EScene&v=1&av=16%2E5%2E2&t=exception
```

I've checked both with the hit validator (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/), and it says they're valid, (although I've altered these slightly so it doesn't contain my personal information, hence the x's, y's, and z's.

When I send it to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect, it gives me back this message:

```
Output multiple:    return {
                      bytesEstimated=-1,
                      bytesTransferred=682,
                      isError=false,
                      name="networkRequest",
                      phase="ended",
                      requestId=userdata,
                      response="{\
                      \"hitParsingResult\": [ {\
                        \"valid\": true,\
                        \"parserMessage\": [ {\
                          \"messageType\": \"INFO\",\
                          \"description\": \"IP Address from this hit was anonymized to 114.35.138.0.\",\
                          \"messageCode\": \"VALUE_MODIFIED\"\
                        } ],\
                        \"hit\": \"/debug/collect?dp=scenes.studio.Scene\\u0026geoid=TESTING\\u0026z=818790\\u0026sr=480x270\\u0026ul=en\\u0026sc=start\\u0026ds=simulator\\u0026dl=scenes.studio.Scene\\u0026dr=iOS\\u0026tid=UA-xxxxxx-1\\u0026ti=TESTING\\u0026cid=TESTING\\u0026aip=1\\u0026an=FE\\u0026cd=scenes.studio.Scene\\u0026aid=xxx.yyy.zzzz.\\u0026v=1\\u0026av=16.5.2\"\
                      } ],\
                      \"parserMessage\": [ {\
                        \"messageType\": \"INFO\",\
                        \"description\": \"Found 1 hit in the request.\"\
                      } ]\
                    }\
                    ",
                      responseHeaders={
                        ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]="*",
                        ["Alt-Svc"]="hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,41,39,35\"",
                        ["Cache-Control"]="private",
                        ["Content-Encoding"]="gzip",
                        ["Content-Type"]="application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
                        Date="Wed, 25 Apr 2018 09:38:44 GMT",
                        Server="MPVS",
                        ["Transfer-Encoding"]="Identity",
                        ["X-Content-Type-Options"]="nosniff",
                        ["X-Frame-Options"]="SAMEORIGIN",
                        ["X-XSS-Protection"]="1; mode=block" 
                      },
                      responseType="text",
                      status=200,
                      url="https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect" 
                    }
```

It looks to me like it came back 200 with no problems.

However, when I send this same hit to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect, so I can see it in the Analytics website's console, I don't see the request appear. It says that there is a user on my app right now (it's me!) but I can't see any of the exceptions or session control events I'm sending -- it shows no events of any kind received today. Is there a reason why this would be happening? Am I missing something in my hit, or do I not know where to look?

Comment: Remember it takes 24  - 48 hours for data to show up in the standard reports.   If its showing up in realtime report then its getting the hit your just going to have to wait and see what pops up in the standard reports.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks @DaImTo

Comment: Ping this question again if it doesnt show up in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to wait 24-48 hours! All set.